# How to set log levels via command line arguments in .NET Core 3

Tags: .net-core-logging, .net-core-configuration

I have a .NET Core 3.0 console application. I have a Microsoft.Extensions.Logging logger and I'm building Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration using a command line arguments.

My question is "How can I set the log levels via command line arguments?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out in the [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#arguments) docs the arguments can be passed in one of the following ways:

```
No prefix   CommandLineKey1=value1
Two dashes  --CommandLineKey2=value2, --CommandLineKey2 value2
Slash (/)   /CommandLineKey3=value3,  /CommandLineKey3 value3
```

Example:

```sh
# Setting Warning level for all microsoft types
dotnet your.dll --Logging:LogLevel:Microsoft=Warning

# or setting Information level for your own types
dotnet run /Logging:LogLevel:YourNamespace:YourType Information
```